# Finding and fixing XSS issues

Tags: php, html, validation, xss

I didnt really know much about XSS before being asked to fix this but I have read several question on stack overflow about it but they havnt seemed to fix my problem.

I am using Whitehat security to check my website for vulnerabilities and It has shown up an XSS issue with a form I have.

It says Parameter Value = $1<%whscheck

and in the description is says:

**Body: first_name=&surname=&email_confirm=&signup_password=whs"onmouseover="prompt()&country=null Mouse over the Password input box to fire the injection.**

which is its way of testing if the form is vulnerable but I am unsure of what the actual problem is or how to fix it.

I have read answer that say use **htmlspecialchars()** when echoing form values so i have done that.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES)
```

Also use **strip_tags()** when sanitizing the inputs so I have done that.

```
$password = ucwords(mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])));
$password = strip_tags($password);
```

but the problem still persists

does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Here is the HTML for the password field

```
  echo "<input type = \"password\" name = \"password\" value = \"" . $password . "\" class = \"newsletter_complete_input\" />\n";
```

and It does get emailed to the user here is the HTML for part of the body of the email

```
$message .= "<a href = \"http://www." . $config_website_short_url . "/confirm.php?c=" .  htmlspecialchars($code, ENT_QUOTES) . md5($code) . "&e=" . htmlspecialchars($code_email, ENT_QUOTES) . "\">http://www." . $config_website_short_url . "/confirm.php?" .  htmlspecialchars($code, ENT_QUOTES) . md5($code) . "&e=" . htmlspecialchars($code_email, ENT_QUOTES) . "</a>";
```

Comment: Maybe use UTF-8? `echo htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` Also, this should be sufficient for the password when you store it: `$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);` making sure to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead of [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php), though you should be using [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: already tried the UTF 8 thing but it didnt work, and mysql_real_escape_string breaks by script but mysql_escape_string doesnt

Comment: @Kevlar Can you provide your HTML? Also, try out my other suggestions (assuming that you're storing your hashed password into the database). Note that your password should be hashed.

Comment: Instead of `strip_tags` use `htmlspecialchars`. they're not the same!

Comment: make the line you think is sending the output comment, see if the same output is being receive by browser!